# Vtiger select multiple contacts

Tags: vtiger

I would like to select multiple contacts to a ticket. I can do this by adding multiple UI Type 10 (e.g Contact 1, Contact 2, Contact 3 etc). I could have 20 or more and it is not very practical. I would really like to add a list like the invoice module when selecting Products. I cannot find what type of UI this is. Can anyone help.

Comment: I found this on vtiger forums but cant figure it out. https://forums.vtiger.com/viewtopic.php?f=104&t=51080

Answer (score 1):

Purpose of vtiger UI type 10 is to map 1 to 1 relation between two records, there is no Multiple UI Type field to enable this. But there is a solution using related lists that implement the 1-Many relation.

Like in Accounts Module where you can select multiple Contacts and add them as related to a certain Account.

You can see this article from vtiger wiki how to add a related list between two modules, if not existing https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Vtlib_Related_Entities

Answer (score 1):

As a suggestion just want to tell you that you can do something like contact field in calendar module during creating Event/call. You can select multiple contact but it will not make 1 to 1 relationship. In calendar module its hard coded but you can do in any module by adding multiple select box and button.